# Undefined variable in postman request

Tags: postman

I have a get request with Tests script as below

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("var1", jsonData.var1);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("var2", jsonData.var2);
```

However response for the request may or may not include all values eg.

response1

```
{
"var1": "value1",
"var2": "value2"
}
```

response2

```
{
"var2": "value2"
}
```

I use above data in next Put request.  Body of the Put request is like below

```
{
  "var1": "{{var1}}",
  "var2": "{{var2}}"
}
```

The issue I am facing is if previous Get request did not have a value for a property (as in response2) then {{var1}} (i.e. variable name) is getting stored in the database (mysql).  I tried removing double quotes around variable in the Put request but that gives me

> invalid character '{' looking for beginning of object key string "

error

Can you please suggest best solution for the situation.

Thanks

Comment: what's your postman version?

Comment: Can you try looping through the data on the first request to see if the `var1`/`var2` property are there, if they are, set them as the variable. The follow on request is slightly more tricky because it's difficult to add logic into the request body - Possibly workflows could help you out there.

Comment: There was a similar fix in postman version 4.10.2, can you verify?

Comment: Version 5.3.2
win32 10.0.16299 / x64